# Console hotkeys

Tags: bash, console

In text editors i like to use hotkeys: ctrl+arrow, ctrl+shift+arrow, ctrl+shift+(end|home).

Is any way to do this in console?

Im using /bin/bash, I know it was many other shells, but I know about they nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, your bash could support <kbd>Alt+F</kbd> for Forward and <kbd>Alt+B</kbd> for Backward. Selection can be started by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+Space</kbd> (or, at least, that's the default in some of the distributions).

Comment: It is possible to change keys for ctrl+* ?

Comment: It might be, see `help bind`.